# Truncated html code in QWebFrame after update

Tags: html, c++, qt, parsing, qtwebkit

I was using **QT 5.3.1 32 bit** but i decided to update my QT to **5.3.2 and 64 BIT**

I have trouble with Parsing HTML code.

My code which was working on 32 bit and 5.3.1

```
std::string html = std::move(output.buffer); // html from curl - all ok
QWebPage * tmp_webpage = new QWebPage();
tmp_webpage->mainFrame()->setHtml(QString::fromStdString(html));
std::fstream test_stream;
test_stream.open("example14.html", std::ios::out | std::ios::in);
test_stream << tmp_webpage->mainFrame()->toHtml().toStdString(); // html is cut in about 50%
test_stream.close();

QWebFrame * tmp_frame = tmp_webpage->mainFrame();
QWebElement mainTable_site = tmp_frame->findFirstElement(QString::fromStdString(mainTable_selector)); // not found because qt cut my correct html
```

This code was working , but now my HTML code which is put to QWebFrame has truncated.

In this code - "test_stream" take expected html code

```
QByteArray html = std::move(output.buffer);
test_stream.write(html);
```

Html code is cut after `</script>`.
QWebFrame appended (at the end - after `</script>`) `</div></div></body></html>` (of course original code is other )

After `</script>`, in original html code i have `<table id="production_table" >` not `</div></div></body></html>`

**Question:**

1. How to set that `setHtml()` won't truncate my html code?
   (i'm using qt to parse some html files, i really dont want take new class (like tidyhtml) and again write code - all was okey but on previous version)

Original HTML code here:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>O rety rety atakują ci z Bety ! (412|412) - Plemiona - Świat 80</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=435365767, app-argument=x-sfp:///visit/tribal-wars">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/apple-icon-iphone-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-icon-ipad-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-icon-iphone4-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-icon-retina-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/merged/mobile.css?1412598051" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/game/overview_base.css?1412598051" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/merged/mobile.js?1412598051"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/game/upgrade_building.js?1408412983"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var image_base = "http://cdn.tribalwars.net/graphic/";
        var mobile = true;
        var mobiledevice = false;
        var game_data = {"player":{"name":"as2d99","ally":"4317","sitter":"0","sleep_start":"0","sitter_type":"normal","sleep_end":"0","sleep_last":"0","interstitial":"0","email_valid":"1","villages":"2","incomings":"0","supports":0,"knight_location":null,"knight_unit":null,"rank":2263,"points":"13019","date_started":"1391362221","is_guest":"0","id":"698410832","quest_progress":"0","premium":false,"account_manager":false,"farm_manager":false,"points_formatted":"13<span class=\"grey\">.<\/span>019","rank_formatted":"2<span class=\"grey\">.<\/span>263","pp":"0","new_ally_application":"0","new_ally_invite":"0","new_buddy_request":"0","new_forum_post":"127","new_igm":"0","new_items":"0","new_report":"0","fire_pixel":"0","new_quest":"1"},"village":{"id":96311,"name":"O rety rety atakuj\u0105 ci z Bety !","wood_prod":0.86666667626364,"stone_prod":0.86666667626364,"iron_prod":0.86666667626364,"storage_max":"400000","pop_max":"24960","wood_float":"400000","stone_float":"400000","iron_float":"400000","wood":400000,"stone":400000,"iron":400000,"pop":"23354","x":"412","y":"412","trader_away":"0","bonus_id":"8","bonus":{"wood":1.3,"stone":1.3,"iron":1.3},"buildings":{"village":"96311","main":"20","farm":"30","storage":"30","place":"1","barracks":"25","church":"1","church_f":"0","smith":"20","wood":"30","stone":"30","iron":"30","market":"20","stable":"20","wall":"20","garage":"15","hide":"10","snob":"1","statue":"1","watchtower":"0"},"player_id":"698410832","res":[400000,0.86666667626364,400000,0.86666667626364,400000,0.86666667626364,"400000","23354","24960"],"coord":"412|412"},"nav":{"parent":2},"link_base":"\/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=","link_base_pure":"\/game.php?village=96311&screen=","csrf":"d199","world":"pl80","market":"pl","RTL":false,"version":"22314 8.27.1","majorVersion":"8.27.1","screen":"overview_villages","mode":null,"device":"desktop"};
        var csrf_token = 'd199';
        var server_utc_diff = 7200;

        var VillageContext = (!VillageContext) ? { } : VillageContext;
        VillageContext.claim_enabled = true;
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body id="ds_body" class="mds">


<div id="mNotifyContainer">
    <div id="notify_incomings" class="mNotify" style="display: none">
        <a href="#" class="mNotifyIcon mNotifyIconAttack"></a>
        <span class="mNotifyNumber">
                0
                </span>
    </div>
    <div id="notify_supports" class="mNotify" style="display: none">
        <a href="" class="mNotifyIcon mNotifyIconSupport"></a>
        <span class="mNotifyNumber"><a class="mNotifyNumber" href="""></a></span>
    </div>
    <div id="notify_mail" class="mNotify" style="display: none">
        <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=mail" class="mNotifyIcon mNotifyIconMail"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="notify_report" class="mNotify" style="display: none">
        <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=report" class="mNotifyIcon mNotifyIconReport"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="notify_forum" class="mNotify" >
        <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;mode=forum&amp;screen=ally" class="mNotifyIcon mNotifyIconAlly"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="mNotify" style="display: none">
        <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=inventory" class="mNotifyIcon mNotifyIconItem"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="loading" ><img src="http://dspl.innogamescdn.com/8.27.1/22314/graphic/m/ajax-loader.gif?df38d" title="" alt="" class="" /><br />Wczytywanie...</div>

<span id="storage" style="display: none">400000</span>

<div id="mobileHeader">
    <div id="mobileTouch">
                <div id="mobileMenu" class="mobileMenu">
            <div id="mobileMenuScroll" class="mobileMenuScrollContent">
                <span class="arrow">&laquo;</span>
                <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=overview">O rety rety atakują ci z Bety !
                <span class="bonus_icon bonus_icon_8" title="30% większa produkcja surowców (wszystkie surowce)"></span>                <b class="nowrap">(412|412) K76</b></a>
                                                - <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=map">Mapa</a>
                - <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=overview_villages">Przeglądy</a>
                - <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=report">Raporty</a>
                - <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=mail">Wiadomości</a>
                - <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;mode=forum&amp;screen=ally"  style="display:inline"><span id="tribe_forum_indicator" class="icon header new_post" title="Nowy komentarz w forum"></span></a><a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=ally">Plemię</a>
                - <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=ranking">Ranking</a>
                - <a href="#" class="needsclick" onclick="$('#mobileMore').toggle(); return false;">Więcej</a>
                                                <span class="arrow">&raquo;</span>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div id="mobileMenuSmall">
                        <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=wood"><span class="mheader icon wood"></span></a> <span id="wood" title="3120" class="warn" data-amount="400000"></span>
            <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=stone"><span class="mheader icon stone"></span></a> <span id="stone" title="3120" class="warn" data-amount="400000"></span>
            <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=iron"><span class="mheader icon iron"></span></a> <span id="iron" title="3120" class="warn" data-amount="400000"></span>
            <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=farm"><span class="mheader icon pop"></span></a> <span id="pop_current_label">23354</span>/<span id="pop_max_label">24960</span>
                    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mobileDivider"></div>
    <div id="mobileMore">
                <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=info_player" class="profile">Profil</a>
                <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=inventory" class="inventory">Inwentarz</a>
                <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=settings" class="settings">Ustawienia</a>
                <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=premium" class="premium">Premium</a>
                <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=buddies" class="friends">Przyjaciele</a>
                <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=memo" class="notebook">Notatki</a>
                <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=flags" class="flags">Flagi</a>
                <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;mode=inventory&amp;screen=statue" class="knight">Rycerz</a>
                <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=accountmanager" class="am">Menedżer Konta</a>
                <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=am_farm" class="fm">Asystent Farmera</a>
                <a href="http://help.plemiona.pl" class="help">Pomoc</a>
                <a href="http://forum.plemiona.pl//index.php" class="extforum">Forum</a>
                <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;action=logout&amp;h=d199&amp;screen=" class="logout">Wylogowanie</a>
            </div>
</div>

<div id="mobileNav">
    <div><span class="mobileNav" id="mobileNavRight"></span></div>
    <div><span class="mobileNav" id="mobileNavLeft"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="mobileNavContent" id="mobileNavContentLeft"></div>
<div class="mobileNavContent" id="mobileNavContentRight"></div>

<div id="mobileContent">
    <div class="menu" style="display:none; padding:3px;" id="group_popup"></div>
        <div class="error_box" style="display:none;">

            </div>





    <div id="content_value" style="margin: 0 auto">



<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    VillageGroups.initOverviews();
});
</script>
<table id="production_table" class="vis small" cellspacing="0">
    <tr style="margin-top:3px;">
    <th style="border-top:1px solid;">
        <span class="quickedit-vn" data-id="96311">
            <span class="quickedit-content">
                <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=overview">
                                                            <span class="quickedit-label" data-text="O rety rety atakują ci z Bety !">
                         O rety rety atakują ci z Bety ! (412|412) K76                     </span>
                    <span class="bonus_icon bonus_icon_8" title="30% większa produkcja surowców (wszystkie surowce)"></span>                </a>
                                <a class="rename-icon" href="#" title="Zmień nazwę"></a>
            </span>
        </span>
    </th>

    <th style="border-top:1px solid;text-align:right;">10<span class="grey">.</span>029</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="nowrap">
    <td colspan="2" class="nopad">
    <a class="button icon show_more">Dalsze informacje</a>
    <div class="more_info">
      <table width="100%">
       <tr><td>Surowce<br /><table><tr><td><span><span class="warn wood">400<span class="grey">.</span>000</span> <span class="warn stone">400<span class="grey">.</span>000</span> <span class="warn iron">400<span class="grey">.</span>000</span> </span></td></tr></table><hr /></td></tr>
       <tr><td class="nopad">
        <table><tr>
            <td style="border-right:1px dotted;">Spichlerz<br /><table><tr><td><span><img  src="http://dspl.innogamescdn.com/8.27.1/22314/graphic/res.png?0fdfc" alt="" title="Pojemność spichlerza" /> 400000</span></td></tr></table></td>
            <td style="padding-left:5px">Zagroda<br /><table><tr><td><span><span class="icon header population"> </span> 23354/24960</span></td></tr></table></td>
        </tr></table>
        <hr /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span>Kupcy</span><br /><table><tr><td><a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;screen=market">110</a></td></tr></table><hr /></td></tr>
              </table>
    </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
    <tr style="margin-top:3px;">
    <th style="border-top:1px solid;">
        <span class="quickedit-vn" data-id="94464">
            <span class="quickedit-content">
                <a href="/game.php?village=94464&amp;screen=overview">
                                                            <span class="quickedit-label" data-text="wioska barbarzyńska">
                         wioska barbarzyńska (412|412) K75                     </span>
                                    </a>
                                <a class="rename-icon" href="#" title="Zmień nazwę"></a>
            </span>
        </span>
    </th>

    <th style="border-top:1px solid;text-align:right;">2<span class="grey">.</span>990</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="nowrap">
    <td colspan="2" class="nopad">
    <a class="button icon show_more">Dalsze informacje</a>
    <div class="more_info">
      <table width="100%">
       <tr><td>Surowce<br /><table><tr><td><span><span class="warn wood">115<span class="grey">.</span>798</span> <span class="warn stone">115<span class="grey">.</span>798</span> <span class="warn iron">115<span class="grey">.</span>798</span> </span></td></tr></table><hr /></td></tr>
       <tr><td class="nopad">
        <table><tr>
            <td style="border-right:1px dotted;">Spichlerz<br /><table><tr><td><span><img  src="http://dspl.innogamescdn.com/8.27.1/22314/graphic/res.png?0fdfc" alt="" title="Pojemność spichlerza" /> 115798</span></td></tr></table></td>
            <td style="padding-left:5px">Zagroda<br /><table><tr><td><span><span class="icon header population"> </span> 1918/2598</span></td></tr></table></td>
        </tr></table>
        <hr /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span>Kupcy</span><br /><table><tr><td><a href="/game.php?village=94464&amp;screen=market">154</a></td></tr></table><hr /></td></tr>
              </table>
    </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.quickedit-vn').QuickEdit( { url: TribalWars.buildURL('POST', 'main', { ajaxaction: 'change_name', village: '__ID__' } ) } );
    });
</script>
</div>

    </div>

    <div style="clear: both">
                    <p style="float: left; margin-bottom: 0">
                <a href="/game.php?village=96311&amp;action=set_mobile&amp;h=d199&amp;mobile=0&amp;screen=settings">Wersja przeglądarkowa</a>
            </p>
                <p style="float: right; margin-bottom: 0">
            <span id="serverTime">21:37:58</span> <span id="serverDate">14/10/2014</span>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="mNotifySpacer"> </div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35100433-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_gat._anonymizeIp']);


  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
  })();

</script>




<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        TribalWars.initTab('9df45365fb');
        Timing.init(1413315478.0743);





            Connection.connect(8080, 'b3267d405e8f');

            UI.Notification.enabled = true;


        });
</script>


<div id="side-notification-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```